# One of our moderators has not logged in since Oct. 23, 2015

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

I just happened to find this and my questions are:

1. Has this moderator been removed from ELU moderatorship automatically in accordance with the absentee policy?

> Any moderator who is not active on the site for a period of six months
>   is subject to removal of their moderator abilities. Moderatorship is
>   an elected position, so if an absentee moderator returns to the site,
>   they may be eligible for reinstatement.

2. Will  there be a moderator election to replace this moderator?

Comment: If there is an election to be held, I would like to recommend danbron and tchrist, to name a few, for moderatorship.

Comment: Link, please. I  don't remember ever seeing this.

Comment: @Mari-LouA The reason why I didn't include any link is very obvious. If you had wanted to find it, you could have found it as soub (who wrote the below answer) did.

Comment: @Rathony Thank you for the endorsement, but you couldn't pay me to be a mod. Also, they don't pay you to be a mod!

Comment: @DanBron I wish I could. I don't think any moderator is doing their job for money or reputation points which mean nothing. I personally saw many instances where you would have done a better job if you had been a moderator. This is an election year!

Comment: I'm sorry the obvious reason for not including the link escapes me. However, here it is: http://modnewsletter.stackexchange.com/2012/01/december-2011- NB: I *was* referring to the citation, not to the question title.

Comment: Related: [Will there be a 2014 Community Moderator election?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4781/will-there-be-a-2014-community-moderator-election?lq=1)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Your linked question is not related as it is not asking about a situation where one moderator hasn't show up for more than seven months.

Comment: @Mari-LouA What makes you think I didn't read your question? Do you mean this part? "there is one mod in particular whose presence I have seen less and less frequently, who seldom posts answers or questions and as far as I can tell, barely participates in meta" I think at least 3 or 4 mods belong to this category now. How is it related when you were talking about a mod who's shown up infrequently and I am talking about one specific mod who seems an MIA.

Comment: It's related, similar, not identical but alike. If you think they're totally unrelated, and the two questions have absolutely nothing in common, I can't do anything about that. P.S Your meta Q speaks about *one* mod, not 3 or 4 mods. But that's fine. You can edit that bit in as well.

Comment: @Mari-LouA In your question, you are basically saying, there are two moderators you want to see replaced. In my question, I am saying one moderator is not doing his duty for more than 6 months. In your question you are asking "how regular are these elections?" and I am asking "Will there be an election to replace that specific moderator?". Your question is about **general election** and my question is about **by-election** I don't really see how these two questions are related.

Comment: If you think we need more moderation help on this site, I think it's better to just propose electing a new mod and leave out the issue of removing old, inactive mods. There doesn't have to be any connection between these two things.

Comment: @sumelic I know what answer I will get when I propose electing a new mod. Why do you think there is no connection between getting rid of inactive mods and electing replacements for them? Why do we need inactive mods? Are they special? Do we need their life-time service? What do they have to offer us until they die? One year leave for study, two year leave for doctoral study, three year leave for assistant professorship? I really don't get it.

Comment: @Rathony - you are making  some interesting points, but you appear to "push" for a new mod election. The only case users are supposed to do that is when there are tangible signs  of lack or inadequacy of site moderation, which, to my knowledge, there are not. A different issue is if you think "moderation" should be conducted in a different way, with a more severe application of rules for instance, which still, I don't think, would be beneficial to the site.

Comment: @Rathony - what I have understood here is that mods are a community within a community, at the service of the larger community but with their own rules, priorities and preferences. It is up to them to decide and, as far  as I can say, their decisions take into account the effects on both their and the larger community. I am sure they are well aware of who's doing what among them, and will react accordingly if needed.

Comment: @Josh61 I know moderators can do whatever they want in terms of managing their affairs. They can manage in whatever way they see fit. If one moderator clicks on ELU.com once in six months, it is enough to keep the post until they die. How ridiculous does it sound? Why do you volunteer for the post when you know you might have to take a year off? That's breach of trust. They have to resign. I don't think anybody would vote for anyone who says "I might have to take a year off." Of course it must have been unexpected. If unexpected things happen, just resign. There are plenty who can replace you

Comment: *I don't think anybody would vote for anyone who says "I might have to take a year off."*  I would. Under the principle of *primum non nocere*, that's the first thing I'd look for in a slate of candidates.

Comment: @deadrat Well, if you are too busy to spend just 10 minutes of your 24 hours 5 days a week, if you expect you to be too busy for your study or whatever, or if you feel you might have to be hospitalized for a long period of time, don't nominate yourself. It is not the US Supreme Court. There is nothing as much sophisticate for any moderator to decide here. Anybody can do it. Don't think you are the only one who can do it. Don't think there are things that only you can do while others can't. Let others who are more free and dedicated do it. You are replaceable as all others elected or nominated

Comment: @Rathony I assume that all the second person pronouns are indeterminate and you're talking about an example moderator. I understand your complaint. I just think absent moderators are better.

Comment: @deadrat Well, I am not complaining. I am reasoning against the ridiculous rule that I can't fathom. I can understand why you think that way. What is the solution? Removal of all moderators and moderatorship itself?

Comment: @Rathony Restriction of moderators to the prevention of site abuse like spam.  Barring that, recognition that anyone who would nominate himself or herself is likely not fit for the job.

Comment: @Rathony You haven't posted a separate question, which is unfortunate. Space is so limited in comments, and comments are not high visibility, and there is plenty to be discussed on this topic.

Comment: @KitZ.Fox Do you mean a Meta SE question? I know exactly what kind of answer I will receive. I don't see any point asking another question on Meta SE. I think this question generated enough discussion on ELU and the next question is when should we decide to remove that moderator and hold a by-election to replace the moderator (if necessary). Or will there be other moderators to be replaced? I think that should be decided in one way or another. I don't want to go to Meta SE and raise this issue because I don't care about other sites where I am not active.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We have this question come up from time to time.

Moderators are sometimes inactive for extended periods of time. We have a mechanism of recording a 'leave of absence', which is helpful for marking vacations as well as longer holidays. We have one mod in particular who took almost a year off to focus on his studies. We manage leaves of absence pretty well and generally have sufficient planning in advance so that the community doesn't notice.

A moderator who is absent without checking in for longer than six months and who hasn't discussed being absent is considered absentee. That just means that we might look into removing moderatorship due to inactivity, as the community changes over time and part of a mod's job is to be aware of and represent those changing needs.

That said, elections are a different matter. We hold elections when the mod team (and-or community moderators) feel that the workload exceeds the current capacity of the moderator team. With an absentee mod, removing a diamond isn't going to have an impact on our workload because we've had months or years to adapt to the shift, so it's unlikely that removing an absentee mod will trigger the need for an election.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Does it mean the moderator gave you a notice of absence and it doesn't matter how long the moderator will be absent from the duty? What is wrong with resigning from the moderatorship and focus on his studies? I mean it doesn't make sense. Nobody is forcing him to maintain the post and if there is a more important thing or issue to take care of, why not just resign?

Comment: @Rathony We don't discuss details of mod absenteeism with the community. There is nothing wrong with resigning as a mod for whatever reason. The mod who chose to take leave for a year wanted to continue as a mod when he returned. He has contributed diligently to handling the workload since he returned to his post.

Comment: I am sorry. I don't get it. We have the right to know what happened exactly as he was elected by the general election. Let me be blunt with you. I think he is very selfish. He should have resigned for a year and let another member to take over the post. The quote in my question clearly states "if an absentee moderator returns to the site, they may be eligible for reinstatement". Then, we can have nine moderators when he returns and if he wants to continue his moderatorship.

Comment: @Rathony Let me be blunt with you. Your opinion is irrelevant. We discussed his planned absence and worked out a solution together. The whole moderation team was fine with the situation. He returned over a year ago, maybe longer than that. There's not much point in making an issue out of it.

Comment: I am sorry. Why is my opinion irrelevant? I am talking about the mod who is missing in action right now for more than seven months. Do you mean he was absent for a year before this absence? Then, I think it makes the matters worse. I see some point in making an issue out of it. You sound like it is something moderators should decide and I have no business in it and I respectfully disagree.

Comment: @Rathony I was talking about a different moderator. As I said, we don't discuss details of mod absences. It is for the moderators to decide and you *don't* have any business in it. You are welcome to post on Meta.SE to generate discussion about community involvement in moderator absenteeism.

Comment: @Rathony Your mistake here is *we have the right to know what happened exactly*. You don't. Nobody does, apart from the community team and the remaining moderator team. I'm sure if you needed to take a few months off from something due to personal, medical, or family issues, you wouldn't appreciate having your personal life spread around on the whim of a stranger on the Internet.

Comment: The reason why I found the absence was I was preparing for Meta SE post to question the legitimacy of "life-time term for moderators" where we can't get rid of inactive or not-active-enough moderators. Let me think  about it. I don't like the way you explained the matter as if moderators were above the rules or any enforcements.

Comment: @ArtOfCode I think you misunderstood my intention. I was saying I have the right to know whether the moderator gave the notice of absence before taking longer than 7 months off. That's all. I don't care to know what happened to him.

Comment: @Rathony Even that is sketchy. People need time out for different reasons; sometimes it just isn't possible to give notice. The community team understand that; no disrespect to you, but site communities and users tend not to.

Comment: @Rathony I don't see anywhere that I'm suggesting that moderators are above the rules. I am interested to see what you propose for getting rid of inactive and not-active-enough moderators.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Well, if you have foreseen or unforeseen issues to take care of (family, health, study, emigration, etc.), I think there is no reason not to resign from the moderatorship as there are other excellent members who can perform the task.  That's my whole point. I think that's why there is such a clause that says a moderator who is absent for more than 6 months could be removed. Why do they have to keep the post as if there were no one else who can replace them and the job couldn't be done without them?

Comment: @Rathony That's on the whole correct, but there are still plenty of cases where it's possible that you can't get in contact with SE to resign.

Comment: @KitZ.Fox Don't you think it is better to hand your job over to another user when you have a planned absence for longer than 6 months?

Comment: @Rathony No, I don't.

Comment: @Rathony More to the point, if you're an elected mod, why hand over? If your absence is planned, why not just say "I'm going to be away from X to Y", and elect another mod without stepping down?

Comment: @Rathony You may be interested in this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151606/handling-calls-to-remove-a-moderator and this one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/984/should-community-moderators-be-elected-for-life-or-have-terms as well as the theory of moderation post. There are several other posts out there about moderators and moderation.

Comment: @ArtOfCode It will depend on how long I will be absent. If I were an elected mod, I would not mind handing it over to another person if I have to take more than six-months off. And basically that's exactly what I said. "We should elect another mod for the period of another mod's absence."

Comment: @KitZ.Fox I read the post before. I think the fundamental problem is the life-time moderatorship. It's not about how to get rid of inactive moderators. The life-time moderatorship gives moderators some leeway that they don't have to be as active as they are supposed to be and that's why some moderators think they can take one-year off. If their terms are limited to two years or three, I don't think it would happen. I don't think users will vote to re-elect moderators who are inactive for a year when there is a re-election.

Comment: @Rathony I am happy to discuss it further once you post your proposal on Meta.SE. I think probably a lot of community members are interested in discussing this topic.

Comment: @KitZ.Fox Well, I lost my appetite to challenge this. I got my answers here and I will forget about it. I'd better spend my time for more productive and useful things than talking to people who think benevolent dictatorship is better. I could have ran for 10 miles while exchanging these comments. I will forget about it. Let the (benevolent) dictators dictate it if that's the SE policy. .

Answer (score 6):

1. No, because there is still a diamond next to their name. The diamond is tied to having moderatorship privileges: one goes with the other.

The [absentee mod policy](http://modnewsletter.stackexchange.com/2012/01/december-2011-newsletter/) states they are subject to removal after 6 months of absence; but when the removal actually happens is flexible. For example, a Seasoned Advice moderator [was removed last month](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2257), after being absent since May 19, 2015. More than a year passed between last login and losing the diamond. In a comment animuson remarked that the absentee mod process is not as straightforward as "x months away, diamond gone".

2. We will know when it's announced. On a site with 8 moderators, if we lost 1, we'd still have 7, which is not sure to trigger an election. It depends on whether the remaining moderators need a reinforcement to effectively moderate the site.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You mean "losing 1 is not sure to trigger an election", right? 1. I understand your point, but sorry I don't think the policy is clear and there is nothing that indicates the removal could be flexible. 2. Seasoned Advice is far smaller community than ELU. I don't think it justifies a delayed removal just because Seasoned Advice has removed its moderator more than a year later. 3. I think it should be decided by the community, not by the moderators. At the end of the day, all communities are run democratically, right?

Comment: @Rathony *all communities are run democratically, right?* - wrong. SE is a benevolent dictatorship. SE give users and communities power and choice where it's possible and useful; in many situations, particularly here, it's not.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Thanks for various comments. You have the point.

Answer (score 5):

A community call for moderator resignation or dismissal due to inactivity is based on a misunderstanding of the relationship between the community and the moderator.

Your view might be that people who run for moderator make promises of performance to the community if elected: promises which they have a duty to the community to fulfill. Perhaps you view moderators as elected representatives, and feel you have rights or vested interests as a member of the community that elects the moderators. From this perspective, a moderator who does not fulfill his duty to the community should resign or be dismissed.

Actually, the duty of a moderator is to Stack Exchange. A moderator is a Stack Exchange volunteer (which is what all of us in the community are). There is no close parallel between moderator campaigns and campaigns in other contexts (such as democratic government). Moderator elections are for Stack Exchange to find out which candidates are credible and best qualified to serve as moderators. A moderator campaign promise is a promise to Stack Exchange, not to the community. The role of the community is to decide whether the promise is credible. After election, it's Stack Exchange, not the community, that the moderator needs to satisfy.

Stack Exchange's inactivity policy helps provide clarity to moderators about what is normally expected of them, but it does not mean Stack Exchange automatically dismisses inactive moderators. Surely Stack Exchange is not looking for reasons to demote volunteers. In fact I imagine it's the opposite: they can use all the good help they can get. What interest would be served by dismissing a good moderator who goes on hiatus and communicates the fact to Stack Exchange?

In comment, you express the view that an inactive moderator stands in the way of giving a new user an opportunity to serve in his place. As far as I know, it is not a zero-sum game. Stack Exchange does not need to demote one moderator before it can appoint another. Moderators can be added or removed as needed.

Comment: Well, I view moderators as no different from any other users who participate in this community. If they have something else to do, they are free to do whatever they want to do. But they should hand over their responsibility and duty to another user as when they were elected, they promised they would do their best to do their job as a moderator. Let's imagine, if that moderator had self-nominated himself as a candidate saying "I will take a year off for my study. But please vote for me." would you have voted for him? I think nobody would have voted for him. That moderator should resign.

Comment: @Rathony Thank you for the clarification -- answer updated.

Comment: Thank you for editing the post (+1). However, I beg to differ. (1) If they were elected and they can't perform their duties, I don't see any reason why they can't resign before SE decides to dismiss them, (2) There are  excellent members (like yourself) who can dedicate more time and energy than the moderator who takes 7 months off. (3) It is more than fair to give new users an opportunity than sticking to his life-term moderatorship, (4) This community would never collapse even if all the moderators were replaced at once. It seems pathetic trying to hold on to the position that never pays.

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: It is perhaps worth mentioning that there used to be 5 moderators before the  2014 election.  Today there are a total of 8, the 3 elected  moderators  are still active members of EL&U. Of the three mods who were less active back in 2014, one of them has recently returned to EL&U and has been moderating a fair bit.